# PostgreSQL fails with invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTFS" :0x00

Tags: postgresql, psql

In the table there is a field "x" of data type character . I am  not able to save it as a null or empty character in db.

Comment: Can you please provide more information?

Comment: Appears to be an encoding problem here. provide more info, and pay special attention to check all the encodings, table, db, file, SO, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot store a NUL character in PostgreSQL, because PostgreSQL uses that character to mark the end of strings.

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html) covers that:

> Regardless of the specific character set, the character with code zero (sometimes called NUL) cannot be stored.